# SweetAlertDialog error after updating Android Studio 3.0 and Gradle version 4.1

Tags: android, gradle

After the update, my application did not make any mistakes, but when I opened the emulator, I could not find the SweetAlertDialog library.Debug mode instead of release apk I tried it on the emulator this time it worked and did not give an error.I do not understand why it gives an error while in Debug mode.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        Process: com.dinlenet, PID: 7427
                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dinlenet/com.dinlenet.activitys.PermissionActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null
                                                            at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:77)
                                                            at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:64)
                                                            at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:41)
                                                            at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.loadAnimation(OptAnimationLoader.java:22)
                                                            at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.<init>(SweetAlertDialog.java:80)
                                                            at com.dinlenet.utils.DialogUtil.showSweetAlertDialogWithListener(DialogUtil.java:27)
                                                            at com.dinlenet.utils.RuntimePermissionsActivity.onCreate(RuntimePermissionsActivity.java:30)
                                                            at com.dinlenet.activitys.PermissionActivity.onCreate(PermissionActivity.java:25)
                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

10-29 08:30:49.083 7427-7427/com.dinlenet E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.

Comment: Post your manifest  file please

Comment: <application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon , android:theme">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this library is the same just with new features https://jitpack.io/p/Leogiroux/sweet-alert-dialog

Answer (score 3):

try to add this line to your proguard file:

```
-keep class cn.pedant.SweetAlert.** { *; }
```

[Reference](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/49) of this Error solution. This is from Git Error issue page of SweetAlaert.

Comment: release apk is already error-free and they are attached to my proguard file.But when I am in debug mode I get this error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependency from build.graddle and add it as a module as shown here:
https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/148

Answer (score 0):

This Library is not maintained

To solve this issue

Modify the File **OptAnimationLoader**

Add another **else condition** / **case**

```
case "YOURPATH.Rotate3dAnimation":
                    anim = new Rotate3dAnimation(c, attrs);
                    break;
```